# Calling Multiple View based on static URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this existing application now user wants me to add a new page.But URL should be same.
i.e.there is already a view name Index.

> http://www.localhost/Index?mdn=&Mdn wdate=&Wdate

Now user wants me to add a new view named **Count** but they wants url should be like this.(except one 
query string.)

> http://www.localhost/Index?mdn=&Mdn count=&Count

I am new in asp.net MVC. Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several ways to achieve that. One way is using `RedirectToAction()`:

```
public ActionResult Index(string count)
    {
        if (count == "Count")
            return RedirectToAction("newActionMethod"); 

        // ... other codes ...
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller action, you can choose which view to render:

```
public ActionResult Index(...)
{
  if (...)
    return View("Count");

  return View(); // returns the default view (in this case "Index")
}
```